# How do I depend on macros from other packages?

Tags: python, elisp-macros

I'm writing a package that provides some Python functionality. I want to use `python-rx`, which is part of Emacs' python.el.

```el
(eval-when-compile (require 'python))

(defun python-foo-starts-defun-p ()
  "Return non-nil if the current statement opens a defun."
  (save-excursion
    (python-nav-beginning-of-statement)
    (looking-at (python-rx defun))))

(provide 'python-foo)
```

However, this gives me byte compilation errors:

```
the function `python-nav-beginning-of-statement' might not be defined at runtime.

the function `python-rx' is not known to be defined.
```

This error is correct: when I run my code in a fresh Emacs, I do get an error about `python-rx`. However, I can open python.el and run `M-x eval-buffer` and then my code works.

I believe this is because `python-rx` is wrapped in an `eval-when-compile` in python.el. How can I use it in my code?

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors, right? You might get away with switching that `eval-when-compile` to `eval-and-compile`.

Comment: I do get a runtime error when I try to call my function. I've clarified this in the question. The suggestion to use `eval-and-compile` is good, as it fixes the `python-nav-...` byte compilation issue, but not the `python-rx` issue.

Comment: There's no need to `eval-and-compile` a `require` statement. If you just want macros you use `eval-when-compile`. If you want functions and macros, you just use the plain `require`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, that `eval-when-compile` method works fine for macros. It is a perfectly good way to use macros (not functions) from another package.

The problems you report are two different things.

> the function python-nav-beginning-of-statement' might not be defined at runtime.

This is happening because `python-nav-beginning-of-statement` is a
function, not a macro. Unlike macros (which are expanded at
compile-time), functions have to be available at runtime. So that
`eval-when-compile` doesn't work here. You need to use a plain
`(require 'python)` to make sure that this function is available.

> the function `python-rx' is not known to be defined.

This is a different warning. This is saying that `python-rx` wasn't found *at all*.
The current stable Emacs (version 24.5) does not have this macro available.

Technically, the macro is there in the file, but it's defined in such a way that makes it unavailable for other files to use.
This has been fixed on the development snapshots (futurely Emacs 25).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding those warnings *in general* (Malabarba's answer covers your specific question nicely)...

When you *know* that a "Warning: the function X is not known to be defined." warning is unnecessary, you can use `declare-function`:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Declaring Functions` <kbd>RET</kbd>

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `declare-function` <kbd>RET</kbd>

More generally, you want to read:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Compiler Errors` <kbd>RET</kbd>